# Using puppeteer login gmail get Couldn't sign you in

Tags: puppeteer

I using puppeteer login Gmail but get this Couldn't sign you in.

[image]

here is some code for login Gmail

```
 await page.goto('https://accounts.google.com/')

  await navigationPromise

  await page.waitForSelector('input[type="email"]')
  await page.click('input[type="email"]')

  await navigationPromise

  //TODO : change to your email 
  await page.type('input[type="email"]', 'your email')

  await page.waitForSelector('#identifierNext')
  await page.click('#identifierNext')

  await page.waitFor(500);

  await page.waitForSelector('input[type="password"]')
  await page.click('input[type="email"]')
  await page.waitFor(500);
```

Comment: my wild guess is it's detecting you as an automated bot. try changing the user-agent and see if that helps

Comment: I tried to use the user-agent but get the same issue.

Comment: Where you ever able to fix this issue? I am having the same problem.